# ListenableFutureCallback - onFailure is never called

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, future

I am playing around with 'ListenableFutureCallback'. onSuccess() works fine, but onFailure is never called. Below is some example code.

```
@Service
public class AsyncClass {

    @Async
    public ListenableFuture<String> execute(Callable<String> callable) throws Exception {
        String str = callable.call();
        //To force an exception to occur
        str.toString();
        return new AsyncResult<>(str);
    }    
}

public void futureMethod(String str) throws Exception {

    AsyncClass asyncClass = new AsyncClass();

    ListenableFuture<String> future = asyncClass.execute(() -> {
        return str;
    });

    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<Object>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object result) {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        }
    });
}
```

onSuccess works correct.

```
futureMethod("test value");
Console: SUCCESS
```

onFailure does however not work.

```
futureMethod(null);
Console: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Comment: I might miss something but don't you create and return the future only _after_ calling `str.toString();`, i.e. when you get the NPE the future wouldn't be created at all?

Comment: That is true. Which would explain why onFailure is never called. I do not understand why onSuccess is still called tho.

Comment: Ahh yeah. onSuccess is of course called because the function does return the expected object, but it cannot detect the exception because it is throw before the future. Brain fart ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using listenable futures.  You are executing code and putting the result in a listenable future.

In order for onFailure to trigger you need to run the failing code inside the future or complete the future with an exception.

For example

```
Futures.immediateFailedFuture(new RuntimeException("woops"));
```

Listenable futures are generally expected to be retrieved from `ListeningExecutorService`s.  `ListenableFuture`, unlike `CompletableFuture`, isn't completable externally.